# Run Powershell script via context menu

Tags: windows, powershell

I have this PS script

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}
dir -Recurse | Unblock-File
```

and i want to run it from the right click menu on a directory so it unblocks all files recursivly

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? SU.SE is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). (That said, this question might be better posted to StackOverflow - but you still will need to show your work. You might also want to take a look at any number of how-tos for "Start PowerShell Here", most of which appear to be possible to modify to suit your needs.)

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far cause i have no idea, otherwise i wouldn't have asked here. Your answer isn't a answer to my question tho. See [How to answer a question](https://no.pe)

Comment: And it's a comment not an answer. ;-) Enough nitpicking, you might want to have a look at [Executing PowerShell script via explorer context menu on items containing ampersands in their names](https://superuser.com/questions/681761/executing-powershell-script-via-explorer-context-menu-on-items-containing-ampers).

Comment: @Bluscream He didn't answer your question, he made a comment telling what to look for. I suggest you pay attention and follow his advice.

Comment: And also [How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders). As Jeff points out there are a quite a lot of HowTos and such that will show you how to add a command to the context menu. If you actually try one of those and get stuck you will probably have more luck asking for help. You really should check the article on what makes a good question.